# AWSFirehoseRecorder saveRecord seems never saving any record

Tags: ios, swift, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-ios, amazon-kinesis-firehose

In app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
    let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: "my-identity-pool-id")
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
    AWSFirehoseRecorder.register(with: configuration!, forKey: "somestupidkey")
```

In view controller

```
let firehoseRecorder = AWSFirehoseRecorder(forKey: "somestupidkey")
let yourData = "Test_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_dataTest_data".data(using: .utf8)
firehoseRecorder.saveRecord(yourData, streamName: kinesisDirectory)

NSLog("Added %d records", firehoseRecorder.diskBytesUsed) // ALWAYS ZERO!!!!
```

It looks like it's not writing data at all. `diskBytesUsed` always returns `0`. Any idea what might be issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved it. It turned to be authentication issue. So using this code will actually catch the error message of why the records weren't submitted:

```
            firehoseRecorder?.saveRecord(jsonData, streamName: "YourStreamName").continueOnSuccessWith(block: { (task:AWSTask) -> AWSTask? in
                NSLog("RecordBeen saved")
                return nil;
            }).continueWith(block: { (task:AWSTask) -> Any? in
                if let error = task.error as? NSError {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                    return nil
                }
                return nil
            })
```

Showing error messages actually helped.

Hope it helps someone else having same issue.

Thanks.